# Fiddler changes proxy setting on enabling Decrypt http traffic option on win 8.1

Tags: c#, google-chrome, fiddler, http-proxy

`My fiddle was working fine until now , but when I'm trying to capture HTTP traffic in fiddler with settings` [image]

```
As I start capturing then Fiddler changes my proxy setting and it loses internet connectivity.
```

My proxy setting before enabling fiddler capturing

[image]

Proxy settings changes once I enable capturing

[image]

```
Also I tried to select and unselect other options like "Act as a system proxy on startup" but no luck and ports other than 8888 but still no luck.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Fiddler is a proxy. So it has to set itself as a system proxy so that traffic flows to it. As a matter of fact it will change your proxy settings when you start it even if HTTPS decryption is not enabled. It needs to be a proxy to capture HTTP traffic, too.

I doubt it loses internet connectivity when you enable HTTPS decryption. Are you sure it's not just the HTTPS connections that experience problems? Doesn't HTTP work? If so then most probably it's a problem with Fiddler generated root certificate and you can reset that from the "Actions" button on your screenshot and try again.